Celery - cannot stop test worker within shutdown timeout
When my celery worker is ready I register a custom timer
@worker_ready.connect
def worker_ready_handler(sender: Consumer, **kwargs):
    logger.info(f"Worker process ready: {sender.pid}")
    timer: Timer = sender.timer
    timer.call_repeatedly(
        60, do_something, ()
    )

When I test it using the celery_worker fixture provided by pytest-celery, I get the error
"RuntimeError: Worker thread failed to exit within the allocated timeout. Consider raising shutdown_timeout if your tasks take longer to execute."
This error only occurs when I have two tests using the celery_worker fixture, I.e.
def test_some_worker_test(celery_app, celery_worker):
    # test a specific task on a worker thread

def test_worker_does_something_periodically(mocker, celery_app, celery_worker):
    # test that the timer is created and doing something periodically...
    # THIS ONE THROWS THE ERROR

I have already tried to increase the shutdown timeout, doesn't help.
When I run the above tests individually, they both work fine.
Could it be that the timer is somehow keeping the worker thread alive and hence the shutdown cannot take place?

Well, remove that timer from the worker_ready_handler and see if you still get the (same) error...

@DejanLekic the point of the unit test was that the logic in worker_ready_handler works, i.e. the task is correctly registered with the timer. Right now I don't have any other solution than to just wait in the test long enough to have at least one timer execution and then asserting..
